# Date Query to Pull Current and Future Posts

Tags: pre-get-posts, date-query

I'm trying to use `date_query` to query posts with todays date or a future date. Think *events*, I don't want to show any posts which has a date before todays date. I'm using `pre_get_posts` and setting the query like so:

```
$query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'future' ) );
$query->set( 'date_query', array(
    array(
        'year'    => date( 'Y' ),
        'month'   => date( 'm' ),
        'day'     => date( 'd' ),
        'hour'    => date( 'G' ),
        'minute'  => date( 'i' ),
        'compare' => '>='
    )
) );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if you mean this kind of `date_query`:

```
$query->set( 'date_query', [
    [
        'after'     => 'today midnight',
        'column'    => 'post_date_gmt',
        'inclusive' => true,
    ],
] );
```

where we use the `after` attribute.

Here the `after` date will be calculated by `WP_Date_Query` as:

```
gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( 'today midnight', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );
```

With the column set as `post_date_gmt`, it generates to the following SQL condition:

```
wp_posts.post_date_gmt >= '2015-04-06 00:00:00'
```

on 6th of April 2015.

### Update - Some Tests:

I ran some tests, trying to understand better the string datetime generation of `WP_Date_Query`:

```
wpse_test( 
    time(), 
    'GMT', 
    'today',
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    '#1 Using time() for blog with UTC-7 and PHP timezone as GMT'
);
wpse_test( 
    time(), 
    'US/Pacific', 
    'today',
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    '#2 Using time() for blog with UTC-7 and PHP timezone as US/Pacific'
);
wpse_test( 
    current_time( 'timestamp' ) , 
    'GMT', 
    'today',
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    '#3 Using current_time() for blog with UTC-7 and PHP timezone as GMT'
);
wpse_test( 
    current_time( 'timestamp' ) , 
    'US/Pacific', 
    'today',
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    '#4 Using current_time() for blog with UTC-7 and PHP timezone as US/Pacific'
);
```

where:

```
/**
 * Test the string datetime generation in WP_Date_Query 
 * with a given timezone and current time
 */

function wpse_test( $time, $timezone, $timestring, $format, $title )
{
    date_default_timezone_set( $timezone );

    printf( '--- %s ---', $title );
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo date_default_timezone_get();
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo $time;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo date( $format, $time );
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo gmdate( $format, $time );
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo date( $format, strtotime( $timestring, $time ) );
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo gmdate( $format, strtotime( $timestring, $time ) );
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

The result is the following output:

```
--- #1 Using time() for blog with UTC-7 and PHP timezone as GMT ---
GMT
1428412051
2015-04-07 13:07:31
2015-04-07 13:07:31
2015-04-07 00:00:00
2015-04-07 00:00:00
--- #2 Using time() for blog with UTC-7 and PHP timezone as US/Pacific ---
US/Pacific
1428412051
2015-04-07 06:07:31
2015-04-07 13:07:31
2015-04-07 00:00:00
2015-04-07 07:00:00
--- #3 Using current_time() for blog with UTC-7 and PHP timezone as GMT ---
GMT
1428386851
2015-04-07 06:07:31
2015-04-07 06:07:31
2015-04-07 00:00:00
2015-04-07 00:00:00
--- #4 Using current_time() for blog with UTC-7 and PHP timezone as US/Pacific ---
US/Pacific
1428386851
2015-04-06 23:07:31
2015-04-07 06:07:31
2015-04-06 00:00:00
2015-04-06 07:00:00
```

We can see that `time()` doesn't change with the timezone and is in GMT.

So it seems that we have to be carefule regarding the timezones!

Comment: I was thinking about the same approach but using `current_time( 'Y-m-d' )` to compare with local time. What do you think? I'm always confused about local time/gmt/db time.

Comment: I see, it uses [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee yes it does and it supports many handy date-time notations ;-)

Comment: I added some extra info to the answer @cybmeta

Comment: So, `date_query` already use `current_time()`? Great to know!!

Comment: It's like opening the Pandora's box trying to dig into this and understand the effect of the timezones ;-) I ran some tests and the conclusion is that we have to be careful with the timezones, no surprize there, but I will keep this answer open and study this further ;-)  @cybmeta

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant with "I'm always confused about local time (read WordPress time zone configuration)/gmt/db time" and I can add "client local time". Good info with the tests. @birgire

Comment: I guess I'm "lucky" in that respect, living in the 'Europe/Reykjavik' timezone that is GMT+0 and is without any summertime changes ;-) @cybmeta